# Datamining and time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, data-mining

Could we say time series forecasting is a part of data-mining or it's just a data-mining tool?

Comment: I would not say either of those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, time series forecasting (when done properly) is data mining.  Most people and software use a pick best approach where they fit a list of models to the data.  One of those 40 models is going to be your winner. That isn't data mining.

Data mining is when you consider these:

Outliers - Level shifts, outliers, trends, seasonality, changes in trend, changes in seasonality (ie Mondays were low and now are average), changes in parameters (CHOW test) and changes in variance (TSAY test). So once you have identified unusual patterns you can macro statements across many time series.  For example, 10% of the time series had a level shift for a given time period.  You can then research why this happened.  It may have been a promotion YOU failed to bring in as a causal or perhaps some other event you weren't aware of and if you researched you can find out why it did.